# KMS crashed while one to many broadcasting with error segmentation fault in KMS error.log

Tags: node.js, segmentation-fault, webrtc, kurento, libnice

We were broadcasting video call among 24 students with one presenter and initially, everything was going well but after 30 mins KMS crashed.
We didn't get any node js error on our server. Kurento was taking very high CPU. There were some errors in KMS log file error.log

We are using KMS Version 6.5.0 and kurento-client 6.2.0.

Client libraries

Language: < Node.js, JavaScript>
Version: v0.10.36

KMS is located on our server and we are using stun server
stunServerAddress=74.125.23.127
stunServerPort=19302

Here is the snapshot of the kurento media server error.log file:

```
[34;1m[gst_base_src_wait_playing] [0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.5.so.0 [32;1m:0x2FB65 [0m
[34;1m[gst_tag_setter_get_tag_merge_mode] [0m
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0 [32;1m:0x9FD7E [0m

(kurento-media-server:596): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_ascii_strcasecmp:      assertion 's1 != NULL' failed

(kurento-media-server:596): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_ascii_strcasecmp: assertion 's1 != NULL' failed

(kurento-media-server:596): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_ascii_strcasecmp: assertion 's1 != NULL' failed

(kurento-media-server:596): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_ascii_strcasecmp: assertion 's1 != NULL' failed
[31;1mSegmentation fault [0m (thread [33;1m140420464244480 [0m, pid     [33;1m596 [0m)
Stack trace:
  [34;1m[SSLv3_client_method] [0m
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 [32;1m:0x23C4E [0m
  [34;1m[SSL_check_chain] [0m
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 [32;1m:0x33E87 [0m
  [32;1m0xCBA2 [0m at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.5/libgstdtls.so
  [32;1m0xECEC [0m at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.5/libgstdtls.so
  [32;1m0x61C1 [0m at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.5/libgstdtls.so
  [32;1m0x644A [0m at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.5/libgstdtls.so
  [34;1m[gst_flow_get_name] [0m
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0 [32;1m:0x6DF85 [0m
  [34;1m[gst_pad_push] [0m
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0 [32;1m:0x75C5E [0m
  [32;1m0x9550 [0m at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.5/libgstdtls.so
  [34;1m[gst_flow_get_name] [0m
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0 [32;1m:0x6DF85 [0m
  [34;1m[gst_pad_push] [0m
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0 [32;1m:0x75C5E [0m
  [34;1m[gst_proxy_pad_chain_default] [0m
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0 [32;1m:0x5F18B [0m
  [34;1m[gst_flow_get_name] [0m
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0 [32;1m:0x6DF85 [0m
  [34;1m[gst_pad_push] [0m
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0 [32;1m:0x75C5E [0m
  [34;1m[gst_base_src_wait_playing] [0m
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.5.so.0 [32;1m:0x2FB65 [0m
  [34;1m[gst_tag_setter_get_tag_merge_mode] [0m
```

we have facing this issue randomaly and we are not able to reproduce.

What is the reason of this error? Is kurento media server is not stable?

If anyone could give any hints, suggestions or directions, I would really appreciate that. Thanks!